# Insert null into Date/Time field in MS Access-

Tags: java, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have been trying to insert `null` values into a `Date/Time` column in MS Access but I keep on getting this error

Below are the variants on how I set the null values

```
String processedDate = ""; // doesn't work
String processedDate = null; // doesn't work
```

The error I get during SQL insert

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression
```

My insert query which is written in Java

```
INSERT INTO DonorDetails ([SIGNUP DATE],Remarks, [Date Processed])values ('25/03/2014','','')
```

Do I have to explicitly construct the SQL statement without the [Processed Date] column when  I know the value is null ? Or is there any easier way ?

Comment: How are you assigning value to the statement? Your java code has no relation to the SQL you've posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clear how are you constructing the query, but a good habit is to create a prepared statement like this:

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO DonorDetails (signup_date, remarks, date_processed) values (?,?,?)");
ps.setTimestamp(1, someTimestamp);
ps.setString(2, someRemark);
ps.setNull(3, Types.TIMESTAMP);
```

This won't be so much dependent on the database and driver used and also solves problems like inserting null(see last line).

P.S. I don't know what the brackets(`[]`) mean in your insert so I just guessed the column names

Comment: I guess I'll have to use the prepared statement. By the way the bracket is for defining table column which contains a space.

Comment: If you are also designing the table, please keep in mind that creating columns with spaces is discouraged. Better use underscore.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL the `null` value must be represented by the keyword `NULL`.

```
INSERT INTO DonorDetails
([SIGNUP DATE], Remarks, [Date Processed])
VALUES (#2014/03/25#, NULL, NULL)
```

```java
String processedDate = "NULL";
```

Comment: my query is written in Java

Comment: No, your query is written in SQL. The `INSERT` statement is clearly a SQL statement. You are using Java in order to construct the text of your query and send it to the DB.

Comment: I used your method and the print out changes to `'NULL'` instead of `NULL`. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: `if (text == null)  insertion = "NULL" else insertion = "'" + text + "'"`. But I recommend using command parameters instead of string concatenations. Those will automatically take care of all these details for you, including the very tricky date formats.